# 1064 error for ALTER AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, mysql-error-1064

Please help, I would like for the table `'order'` to auto increment starting at `14000`, but no matter what I try, I keep getting the below error?

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE order AUTO_INCREMENT = 14000;
```

> `ERROR 1064 (42000)`: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near `'order AUTO_INCREMENT = 14000'` at line 1

I have performed a number of searches and so far as I can tell this is the correct syntax.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the create table statemt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table has named `ORDER`. But *ORDER* is a reserved word. Use ` and then the table name ORDER.

In this way

```
`order`
```

Comment: +1. Formatted to reflect your intention of answering.

Comment: @Ravinder: Thanx, I've tried to format but I can't obtain your result (now I study the correct method) ;)

Answer (score 0):

try to execute using this,

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `order` AUTO_INCREMENT = 14000;
```

`order` is actually an `SQL keyword`. You would have the same problem if you tried to use a table called `group` or `select`. You can fix it is MySQL by using `quotes` around it.

Answer (score 0):

`Order is Keywords in MySQL`. You need to surround it in `backticks`.

Like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `order` AUTO_INCREMENT = 14000;
```

Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Else paste the complete create table statemnt.

Answer (score 0):

`order` is a [**reserved**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) keyword

So try this..use backticks

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `order` AUTO_INCREMENT = 14000;
```